# dymaically changing the meta tag values!! works fine with debug tool but not working while posting with graph api explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am posting an Open Graph "Level Up" action however while I am testing I am getting strange results. I have set the code to dynamically change the title so that it says Level "1", Level "2" etc.

> url.php?level=6

. and this works perfectly on the debug tool, updating the title with whatever parameter value I pass in.  The problem comes when I actually try to post using the Graph API Explorer tool. For some reason whatever parameter I pass, ie. =1, =2, it doesn't seem to take the parameter value.  Has anybody encountered the same problem?

Comment: What does [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) show? are you sure you're not accidentally using the same `og:url` value on all objects?

Comment: debug tool gives the updated title using the value of the level parameter i pass. i have created only one object and im dynamically trying to change my og title using the parameter passed.

Comment: No, each object URL needs a static title, you can't change it per-publish; use a different URL for each unique object / title

Comment: so if i want to create diffrent titles like Level One, Level two etc do i have to create differnt url for each one rather than passing the value of the level as parameter in the url? im calling it like www.url link.php?level=4

Comment: the problem seems to me while psoting in the graph api explorer is it seems to not taking the parameter value, it take only the default value and it gives title as  Manager Level 100  
<?php
$params = array();
if(count($_GET) > 0) {
    $params = $_GET;
} else {
    $params = $_POST;
}
// defaults
if($params['level'] == "") $params['level'] = "100";
?>  <meta property="og:title"       content="Manager Level <?php echo $params['level']; ?>" />

Comment: No, you can pass it in the URL, but the og:url tag on that page needs to point to the same URL with the same parameters, and you need to be sure that the facebook crawler is receiving the correct og:url value

Comment: thanks for your replies.i did excatly same and it works fine with debug tool but when i try  post or get in graph api explorer it seems like ITS NOT TAKING THE PARAMETER VALUES hence it uses the default value for the parameter in the og meta data. is ther any thing else i need to do to read the url parameter values asweell?

Answer (score 1):

You can post request in Windows using Fiddler. Don't forget to set User-agent header (if you really check it).
I have the same issue. Checked my logs: FB does not even try to load my object by specified URL! After checking link in Debug Tool or making a request from Graph API Tool it will work.
There's already [bug report on FB](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/309812472446235)

Comment: I finally got rid of FB error "Could not retrieve data from URL". My mistake was simple and stupid: I used something like "/blablabla.php?id=2&amp;arg=2", but it should be "/blablabla.php?id=2&arg=2". &amp; is used only in HTML

Answer (score 0):

Each URL needs to be accesible by [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and needs to be be internally consistent without redirects or loops.

If on a page, you have an `og:url` tag, Facebook will load that URL instead, so if your URL includes parameters which control the output of the meta tags, the og:url tag needs to include the **same** parameters which loaded the page in the first place.

If you're not sure what the debug tool is seeing, and don't trust it for some reason, you can make a manual request using curl on the command line to see what Facebook is detecting:
`url -A "facebookexternalhit/1.1" -i [URL GOES HERE]`

Comment: how to make a manually request using curl? is it just to copy the code: url -A "facebookexternalhit/1.1" -i [atual url] in the debug tools, debug input area?

Comment: No, in your command shell (Terminal on OSX, Terminal on most linux systems, 'command line' in windows i think - http://superuser.com/questions/134685/run-curl-commands-from-windows-console has details for windows